# Android Awareness API multiple fence registration

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence, google-awareness

I am trying to register multiple location fences using Androids awareness API over multiple sessions. But every time I register a new location fence, it seems to drop my old location fences and not trigger them any more.

```
String uniqueId = UUID.getid().toString() // sample to indicate this is always 
unique
AwarenessFence geoFence = LocationFence.in(lat, long, radius);
            Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
                        googleApiClient,
                        new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                                .addFence(uniqueId, geoFence, pendingIntent)
                                .build())
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback () { .....});
```

My Pending Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GeoBroadcastReceiver.BROADCAST_KEY);
        Bundle bundle;
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("model", model);
        intent.putExtra("specialBundle", bundle);
        PendingIntent geoBroadCastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

> The docs say this is how to add fences, but I wonder do i need to keep
>   track of my old fences and anytime i use
>   `Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences`, I need to add them in every-time?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is old question but I will answer nonetheless, somebody may find it usefull. Recently I had similiar problem and I managed to solve it.

In your code you are setting every pending intent same requestCode. Because of that and flag FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT you are overiding all previous pending intents(you are always setting 0). So to make it work you have to set unique requestCode to every pening intent

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your fence key.

As discussed in [Register a fence](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-register#register_a_fence_1), the following things are required to register a fence:

- A [Google Play Services API Client](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-started#connect_to_the_awareness_api) instance.
- An `AwarenessFence` instance (the fence itself).
- A `PendingIntent` to handle state changes.
- A fence key (a string which identifies the fence, and maps to an `AwarenessFence`/`PendingIntent` pair).

Also note that, if you call `addFence()` using a fence key that has already been registered, the `AwarenessFence` and `PendingIntent` values are overwritten for that key.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Right the fence key was the first thing I checked, we set a new unique fence key every time, so that is definitely not the issue. I wonder if we have to re-register all the fences again every-time we use `updateFences`